# Array into mysql row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hello i have a dynamic form that can change field names upon user selection. i would like for the form result to be inserted into one mysql row.. i create an array as follows:

```
<?php

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['item_name'])) {
        $table = $_POST['ItemTypeSelect'];

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $variable) {
            $chesckColumn = mysql_query("SELECT `$key` from $table");
            if (!$chesckColumn) {
                echo "column ".$key." does not exist <br/>";
            }else{
                $results = $variable;
                $columnName = $key;
                $array[] = array($columnName => $results);
            }
        }
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (`$columnName`) VALUES ('$results') ")or die(mysql_error());

        }

?>
```

my array result are

```
 (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Server_id] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Server_IP_Address] => 12345
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Server_IP] => 12345
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [Server_Name] => dad
        )

)
```

How can i have the array be inserted in one table row and reference the $results and the field value and $columnName as the field value.

Comment: Try getting the data out of the array into separate variables, and then perform the insertion.

Comment: @Yisera I was getting the data separately, but that only insert one field.

Comment: Ok first of all, may I recommend you stop using mysql, it is outdated. Try mysqli (MYSQL improved extension) which has a beautiful OO interface, or PDO.

Comment: ALso, if it may help. When updating mysql, the server_IP and Server_IP_Address are NULL. for some reason its not passing the field value. but i can see the post in firebug include the information.

Comment: What is the result of `mysql_error()` after your query?  Also, as Yisera says, use [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/pdo).  The mysql_* library is deprecated and its usage is discouraged.

Comment: @Crackertastic No error - If i use the code as above (ignoring the array) i am able to update the table - but all Int columns are updated with null value.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?  I see where you are doing and insert on a single column, but I don't see any `UPDATE` statements.  If your other columns not specified in your `INSERT` statement allow null values (and no default value specified), that would be why null values are being inserted.

Comment: @Crackertastic for now i am only inserting values in the table. from looking around it looks like the Int fields are not inserted due to the quotation around the value. So i am not sure how to remove them since they are a must to have.

Comment: Hmmm...I am thinking that the quotes shouldn't matter.  MySQL is pretty good about casting values like that.  Another thing that shouldn't matter (but I would try) is removing backticks from your field names and concatenating your values in the string. e.g.: `"INSERT INTO $table (".$columnName.") VALUES ('".$results."')"`

Comment: @Crackertastic tried it :) but still same issue

Comment: Could it be that its only updating the last field.. and not the first two thats why it's set to null??

Comment: At this point I would start `var_dump`-ing your variables to see what values you are sending to your query.  I might also construct the query as a string (with interpolated values) and then give that string to an SQL client to see if it executes that way. If it still works then the issue probably lies with the logic of the query (i.e. not programmed to perform the intended result).  But of course, that is already apparent :-)

Comment: what about the array option for inserting the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a few php built in functions:

```
function put_quotes(&$item){
    $item = "'$item'";
}
$columns = implode(",",array_walk(array_keys($_POST),'put_quotes'));
$values = implode(",",array_walk(array_values($_POST),'put_quotes'));

mysql_query("INSERT INTO $table (columns) VALUES ($values) ")or die(mysql_error());
```

Where :

- [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php) executes a function over all array, here put quotes over the item.
- [array_keys](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-keys.php) gets the keys from an array
- [array_values](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-values.php) gets the values from an array
- [implode](http://php.net/function.implode) joins an array to a string with a separator

Answer (score 0):

Use **PDO** because **mysql_*** functions are depreceated.

Connect to **MySQL** in **PDO** :

```
$db="database";
$host="127.0.0.1";
$usr="username";
$pass="password";
$dbh=new PDO("mysql:dbname=$db;host=$host", $usr, $pass);
```

First convert the **array** to **JSON** and save it on the table :

```
$json=json_encode($array);
$sql=$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO ? (?) VALUES (?)");
$sql->execute(array($table,$columnName,$json));
```

If you want to retrieve the array back, decode the **JSON** data got from table:

```
$sql=$dbh->prepare("SELECT ? FROM ?");
$sql->execute(array($columnName,$table));
while($r=$sql->fetch()){
 $array=json_decode($r[$columnName],true);
 print_r($array);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the whole site is in mysql, and i am not familiar with PDO as i am still in the learning process of mysql and php